# Collecting stored variable property using withLatestFrom

Tags: ios, rx-swift, reactive

I'm wondering if there is a way in RxSwift to observe value of stored variable property. Eg. in following example:

```
    var updatedValue: Int = 0

    var observedValue: Observable<Int> {
            return Observable.create({ (observer) -> Disposable in
                observer.onNext(updatedValue)
                return Disposables.create()
            })
        }

    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
        updatedValue = updatedValue + 1;
    }

    let myObservable = Observable<Int>.interval(1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .publish()

    myObservable.connect()

    myObservable
        .withLatestFrom(observedValue)
        .subscribe { (event) in
            print(event)
    }
```

We have variable property **updatedValue** and hot observable **myObservable**. We also increment value of updatedValue in *Timer.scheduledTimer...*.

Flow here is pretty straight forward. When we subscribe, observedValue gets called, we get onNext from observedValue and then Disposables.create(). Then we print event onNext(0).

As **myObservable** is based on *Observable.interval*, same withLatestFrom value gets printed in onNext every second.

Question: Is there a way to print last value of updatedValue every time myObservable emits new event? So instead of 0,0,0... we get 0,1,2...

I'm aware that updatedValue could be declared as BehaviorRelay.
I'm also aware that we could use .map { } to capture self.updatedValue.

But I'm wondering if there is any way to create a Observable wrapper around standard variable property so it calls onNext with most recent value every time trigger sequence sends an event? Without capturing self or changing declaration on updatedValue.

Thanks for any comments and ideas!

Comment: How about using rx KVO observation? It's fairly straightforward to observe changes of a stored property in a class.

Comment: @TonyNguyen indeed! That's exactly what I meant.
let updatedValueObservable = self.rx.observe(Int.self, "updatedValue") seems to do the trick without any additional operators. Can you please post your comment so I can mark it as accepted one? ;)

Comment: Hey, thanks! I've posted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RxCocoa has a handy wrapper around KVO. You should be able to use it from `.rx` extension on NSObject subclasses.

For your issue, I guess you can do something like:

```
let updatedValueObservable = self.rx.observe(Int.self, "updatedValue")
```

Answer (score 1):

> But I'm wondering if there is any way to create a Observable wrapper around standard variable property so it calls onNext with most recent value every time trigger sequence sends an event? Without capturing self or changing declaration on updatedValue.

The correct answer is, no. There is no way to do anything to `updatedValue` without involving self. One way of doing it would be with `Observable<Int>.interval(1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance).compactMap { [weak self] _ in self?.updatedValue }.distinctUntilChanged()` (Your use of publish and connect is odd and unnecessary,) but that involves self.

Since your property is a value type, the only way to access it is through self, even if Rx wasn't involved at all.

Comment: Sorry, I think despite of length of my question I still managed to not describe clear enough what I was looking for. What I meant is to find a way to observe property changes without introducing any additional and unnecessary operators. Rx KVO Observation seems to be just what I was looking for ;)

Thanks for an answer, nevertheless! 

PS Is using weak self necessary in example you've provided? If we don't have dispose bag held strongly by a class that also stores property updatedValue there should not be a risk of retain cycle, should there?